# use BTEQ to schedule a query in windows

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, teradata

Hi I'm pretty new using BTEQ,

I'm looking to schedule a query that runs using teradata connection, the query results should go to an excel or txt with separators (so it can be formatted using excel)

I need to to this through windows, so I guess it should be a *.bat scheduled using windows scheduler

The things is that I don't have a clue how to open the connection, running the query and exporting the result to a *.xls or *.csv or *.txt

I have set already the ODBCs to connect to TD (I use the TD administrator and run the query manually everyday).

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 1):

BTEQ doesn't use ODBC but a CLI connection.

You can simply create a script like this:

```
.logon TDPID/username,password; 

.OS if exist bla.txt del bla.txt; -- remove the file if it exists (otherwise BTEQ appends)

.export report file = bla.txt;

SELECT
   TRIM(DataBaseName) || ',' ||
   TRIM(TableName) || ',' ||
   TRIM(Version) || ',' ||
   TRIM(TableKind) || ',' ||
   TRIM(ParentCount) (TITLE '')
FROM dbc.TablesV 
SAMPLE 10
;

.export reset;

.EXIT;
```

`TDPID` is the name of your TD system (or an IP-address).

You need to manually format the csv in the SELECT as shown above using `TRIM` and `||` and you have to take care of possible NULLs using `COALESCE(TRIM(col), '')`.

You might also try the ancient DIF format, no need to care about NULLs, etc.

```
.export DIF file = bla.dif;

SELECT
   DataBaseName    
  ,TableName
  ,Version  
  ,TableKind
  ,ParentCount     
FROM dbc.TablesV
SAMPLE 10
;
```

In TD14 there's a table UDF named CSV which takes care for NULLs and quoting strings instead of `TRIM`/`COALESCE`/`||`. Thy syntax is a bit lengthy, too:

```
WITH cte
 (
   DataBaseName    
  ,TableName
  ,Version  
  ,TableKind
  ,ParentCount     
 )
AS
 (
SELECT
   DataBaseName    
  ,TableName
  ,Version  
  ,TableKind
  ,ParentCount     
FROM dbc.TablesV
SAMPLE 10
 )
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE(CSV(NEW VARIANT_TYPE
    (
      cte.DataBaseName    
     ,cte.TableName
     ,cte.Version  
     ,cte.TableKind
     ,cte.ParentCount     
    ), ',', '"')
   RETURNS (op VARCHAR(32000) CHARACTER SET UNICODE)) AS t1;
```

Finally you run BTEQ and redirect the file (you can put this is an BAT file):

```
BTEQ < myscript.txt
```

There might be other options, too, e.g. a TPT/FastExport script or putting the SQL inside an Excel file which automatically runs the query when opened...